# How to solve this challenge using Subquery in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm trying to solve this challenge by using Subquery, I don't know what are the syntax wrong in my code.

```
select h.hacker_id, h.name from hackers

        join (
                select s.submission_id, s.hacker_id, s.score, d.score
                        from submissions s
                        join challenges c on c.challenge_id = s.challenge_id and
                                                c.hacker_id = s.hacker_id
                        join diffculty d on c.difficulty_level = d.difficulty_level
                        where (s.score = d.score) 
                        group by s.submission_id

        ) as Result(SubId, HID, D1, D2)

        on h.hacker_id = Result.HID
        having count(Result.SubId) > 1
        order by count(Result.SubId) desc, h.name;
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SubId, HID, D1, D2)

        on h.hacker_id = Result.HID
        having count(R' at line 12
```

this is the link of challenge: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/full-score/problem

Comment: 'as Result(SubId, HID, D1, D2)' - never seen this syntax before do you have a reference for it?

Comment: In context those lecture notes may be fine but in mysql Result(SubId, HID, D1, D2) it's not. In mysql you should alias the columns within the sub query. AND in most versions of sql a group by without any aggregations would cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to (re)name the columns in the table expression itself as in:

```
select h.hacker_id, h.name 
from hackers

    join ( -- here you started a "table expression"
            select s.submission_id as SubId, -- renamed here 
                   s.hacker_id as HID,       -- renamed here
                   s.score as D1,            -- renamed here
                   d.score as D2             -- renamed here
            from submissions s
            join challenges c on c.challenge_id = s.challenge_id and
                                 c.hacker_id = s.hacker_id
            join diffculty d on c.difficulty_level = d.difficulty_level
            where (s.score = d.score) 
            group by s.submission_id

    ) as Result on h.hacker_id = Result.HID
group by h.hacker_id -- you need to group if you want to use HAVING
having count(Result.SubId) > 1
order by count(Result.SubId) desc, h.name;
```